# Help on Axis2 Deployment Exception

Tags: apache-axis, resin

I am currently working on Axis2 deployed on Resin 3.1.3. However, I got the below error during deployment:

org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The "Dispatch" phase is not found on the global "InFlow" phase of the axis2.xml file. Make sure the phase is within the axis2.xml file.

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

-Angel

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/0_94/axis2config.html), underneath the "Phase Order" heading.  That should let you know how you need to define the Dispatch phase in your axis2.xml.

It's also possible that the axis2.xml file can't be found or is missing.  You haven't provided many details so it's hard to be more specific than that.

Edit:

Remember that Axis2 is a standalone web application that is deployed into a servlet container.

You indicated in your comments that you modified your web application's web.xml.  You should not need to do that to get Axis2 to work properly, so you can remove those mappings and redeploy your applications.

Try [this guide](http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-deploy-apache-axis2-on-resin-and.html).  Make sure that you can see the "Axis2 Happiness" page described in step 6.

Once you have that working, you can go back to your other web applications and start modifying them to call your web services.

Comment: Hi Michael,
thank you for the response. Sorry for not providing much details.I created a webservice in Axis2 and is trying to embed it in our existing application.I dropped axis2.war in c:/resin/webapps then modified web.xml of our apps to include axis2 mapping. But when i deployed resin, i got the above error. I checked axis2.xml and its in C:\resin\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\conf. I did not do any modifications in axis2.xml so I am wondering why it can't see the Dispatch phase.